# Calculating Bull/Bear Markets in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I was recently given a challenge of calculating the presence of Bull/Bear markets using the values of -1, 1 to denote which one is which.

It is straight forward enough to do this with a for-loop but I know this is the worst way to do these things and it's better to use numpy/pandas methods if possible.  However, I'm not seeing an easy way to do it.

Any ways of how to do this, maybe using changes of +/- 20% from current place to determine which regime you're in.

Here's a sample dataframe:

```
dates = pd.date_range(start='1950-01-01', periods=25000)
rand  = np.random.RandomState(42)

vals    = np.zeros(25000)
vals[0] = 15

for i in range(1, 25000):
    vals[i] = vals[i-1] + rand.normal(0, 1)

df = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=['Price'], index=dates)
```

The plot of these prices looks like this:

[image]

Anyone have any recommendations to calculate what regime the current point is in?

If you have to use a for loop then that's fine.

Comment: You did not specify what you consider a bull or bear market... 20% change versus what? Versus the recent high/low? Or 20% versus six months ago? Or a year ago?   A daily indicator will have a lot of thrashing, which you don’t address.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work:

```
import numpy as np
vals = np.random.normal(0, 1, 25000)
vals[0] = 15
vals = np.cumsum(vals)
```

Comment: This would give you the current asset price based on the daily returns, but it wouldn't calculate whether or not the sample was in a bull or bear market -- you would need to have some way of calculating how far away each sample is from the previous peak.

Comment: That's true; this was more directed at your question on replacing the for-loop. The bull-vs-bear market determination would require more background about the criteria involved which I'm not really familiar with,.